# Problems adding UISwitch in CCLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Good day,

My problem is that I have a settings screen which is a CCLayer and I want to display a UISwitch in it. I have used this code in my settings.m

```
    UISwitch * soundSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,150,0,0)];
    [soundSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(soundButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:soundSwitch];
```

But now the switch is displayed right after the game is launched. I want it to appear only when my settings layer is initialized. Any help in this regard?

Comment: that means settingsLayer already initialized. Once again check...

Comment: no [SettingsLayer node] is called upon pressing Settings button on another layer. But UISwitch is shown right after the game is launched.

Comment: also it remains there even when I push another scene.

Comment: All UI related thing are added on top most scene, you want navigate one scene to another you have to remove all UI related things.

Answer (score 0):

try to add switch as

```
UISwitch * soundSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,150,0,0)];
    [soundSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(soundButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubview:soundSwitch];
```

i,e use [[[CCDirector sharedDirector]openGLView]addSubview:soundSwitch] instead.

and one more thing your initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,150,0,0) make no sense as 0 length and 0 width is of no significance.Try some valid coordinates like (130,210,30,30)